# ¿Cómo creo una cuenta aleatoria de 3 letras y 3 números con UUID?

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println (UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase().subSequence(0,6));
```

Esto lo que hará es tirar un alfanumérico de tamaño 6, pero necesito 3 números y 3 letras específicamente.

Comment: Hola Sofia. Y qué has intentado? Has investigado esos metodos `random` para adaptarlos? Necesitamos que muestres tus pruebas y errores para poder ayudarte. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. un saludo

Comment: Si, el enunciado solamente fue crear una cuenta de 6 caracteres, 3 letras y 3 numeros. Y he estado investigando y UUID me permite hacerlo, pero no sé si se podrá con el.

Comment: Y qué has intentado para filtrar y que salgan solo letras y solo numeros?  Igual usar UUID no es la mejor manera. Has mirado otras?  Para numeros hay maneras de sacar numeros aleatorios en un rango (001-999) y para letras puedes hacer un array de caracteres y sacar 3 de manera random .

Comment: Realmente no es un alfanumérico, UUID son números en formato hexadecimal, por lo que sólo verás letras de la A a la F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo uso de lo que tienes se me ocurrió hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crear una cadena de texto a partir de la clase `UUID` en mayúsculas.
2. Crear dos *Streams* de caracteres( `Stream<Character>`)

   - Uno que filtre 3 dígitos
   - Uno que filtre 3 letras
3. Concateno los dos *Streams* y genero una lista de caracteres (`List<Character>`)
4. Los mezclo para evitar tener la estructura de 3 dígitos al principio y 3 letras al final.
5. Por último paso la lista a una cadena de texto.

### Código

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase();
Stream<Character> digit = uuid.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).filter(Character::isDigit).limit(3);
Stream<Character> alpha = uuid.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).filter(Character::isAlphabetic).limit(3);
List<Character> collect = Stream.concat(digit, alpha).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(collect);
String finalString = collect.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

### Salida

```
CA2E58
```

### Documentación

- [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)
- [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
- [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Answer (score 0):

No creo que utilizar UUID sea la mejor forma para crear una clave de 6 caracteres, pero si lo que realmente es lo que estás buscando, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
    UUID auxiliar = UUID.randomUUID();
    String clave = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <auxiliar.toString().length (); i++) {
        char c = auxiliar.toString().charAt(i);
        //.... comparas si son letras o numeros y guardas los que necesitas.
    }
```

Crea de forma auxiliar un objeto UUID y recórrelo usando el método toString(), cada dato que obtengas lo analizas de acuerdo a cuantas letras y números necesites. Puedes usar un contador de letras y otro para números e ir sumando 1 cada vez que encuentras un valor que te sirva y este valor lo guardas en el String clave.